# Resource strings in .net

Tags: .net

I have few .net dll's and each dll has a resource.resx file which stores some exception messages used in the project.

My question is whether it is good to have resource file in the dll itself or just have a single dll which stores the resource strings required for all the dlls of the project.

What are the adv/disadv of both the practice.

Thanks,
Latha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resource.resx is a format consists of XML entries, which specify objects and strings inside XML tags. It is basically used for multilingual support in a project/website.
It is a good practice to put resource file inside App_GloablResources folder.
If your dll file contains resoucre file no issues.But later on i t can create problems in managing these resource file.But it is good to have them in one place.It creates the project in a more structured way and easy to manage.